# jquery and requirejs and knockout; reference requirejs object from within itself

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, requirejs

We use jquery and requirejs to create a 'viewmodel' like this:

```
define('vm.inkoopfactuurAanleveren',
['jquery', 'underscore', 'ko', 'datacontext', 'router', 'messenger', 'config', 'store'],
function ($, _, ko, datacontext, router, messenger, config, store) {
    var
        isBusy = false,
        isRefreshing = false,
        inkoopFactuur = { factuurNummer: ko.observable("AAA") },           
        activate = function (routeData, callback) {
            messenger.publish.viewModelActivated({ canleaveCallback: canLeave });
            getNewInkoopFactuurAanleveren(callback);              
            var restricteduploader = new qq.FineUploader({                    
                element: $('#restricted-fine-uploader')[0],
                request: {
                    endpoint: 'api/InkoopFactuurAanleveren',
                    forceMultipart: true
                },
                multiple: false,                 
                failedUploadTextDisplay: {
                    mode: 'custom',
                    maxChars: 250,
                    responseProperty: 'error',
                    enableTooltip: true
                },
                text: {
                    uploadButton: 'Click or Drop'
                },
                showMessage: function (message) {                        
                    $('#restricted-fine-uploader').append('<div class="alert alert-error">' + message + '</div>');
                },
                debug: true,

                callbacks: {
                    onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                        var response = responseJSON;
                    },
                }
            });
        },

       invokeFunctionIfExists = function (callback) {
           if (_.isFunction(callback)) {
               callback();
           }
       },

        loaded = function (factuur) {
            inkoopFactuur = factuur;
            var ids = config.viewIds;
            ko.applyBindings(this, getView(ids.inkoopfactuurAanleveren)); /*<----- THIS = OUT OF SCOPE!*/                /
        },

        bind = function () { },

        saved = function (success) {
            var s = success;
        },

        saveCmd = ko.asyncCommand({
            execute: function (complete) {
                $.when(datacontext.saveNewInkoopFactuurAanleveren(inkoopFactuur))
                        .then(saved).always(complete);
                return;
            },
            canExecute: function (isExecuting) {
                return true;
            }
        }),

        getView = function (viewName) {
            return $(viewName).get(0);
        },

        getNewInkoopFactuurAanleveren = function (callback) {
            if (!isRefreshing) {
                isRefreshing = true;                    
                $.when(datacontext.getNewInkoopFactuurAanleveren(dataOptions(true))).then(loaded).always(invokeFunctionIfExists(callback));
                isRefreshing = false;
            }

        },

        dataOptions = function (force) {
            return {
                results: inkoopFactuur,
                // filter: sessionFilter,
                //sortFunction: sort.sessionSort,
                forceRefresh: force
            };
        },

        canLeave = function () {
            return true;
        },            

        forceRefreshCmd = ko.asyncCommand({
            execute: function (complete) {
                //$.when(datacontext.sessions.getSessionsAndAttendance(dataOptions(true)))
                //    .always(complete);
                complete;
            }
        }),                        

        init = function () {
           // activate();
            // Bind jQuery delegated events
            //eventDelegates.sessionsListItem(gotoDetails);
            //eventDelegates.sessionsFavorite(saveFavorite);

            // Subscribe to specific changes of observables
            //addFilterSubscriptions();
        };

        init();

    return {
        activate: activate,
        canLeave: canLeave,
        inkoopFactuur: inkoopFactuur,
        saveCmd: saveCmd,
        forceRefreshCmd: forceRefreshCmd,
        bind: bind,
        invokeFunctionIfExists: invokeFunctionIfExists                  
    };
});
```

On the line `ko.applyBindings(this, getView(ids.inkoopfactuurAanleveren));` in the 'loaded' method
the 'this' keyword doens't refer to the 'viewmodel' object.
the 'self' keyword seems to refer to a combination on methods found over multiple 'viewmodels'.
The saveCmd property is bound through knockout, but gives an error since it cannot be found.

How can the ko.applyBindings get the right reference to the viewmodel?
In other words, with what do we need to replace the 'this' keyword int he applyBindings.

I would imagine you can 'ask' requirejs to give us the ealiers instantiated object with identifier 'vm.inkoopfactuurAanleveren' but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

just use this line right after the line `function ($, _, ko, datacontext, router, messenger, config, store) {`

```
var me = this;
```

and then use me where ever you need to refrence
*note this might not be the best way but this is how i dont it --  everything under cntrl

Comment: I will give this a quick try too, as a quickfix this seems the easiest way, however, this is not really a long term solution.

Comment: This doesn't work, this is already out of scope at that point and doesn't refer to the viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing does not come from RequireJS but from the way you are creating your viewmodel and the fact that you are not paying attention to what the "this" is in your functions.

From reading your code I can tell you that the "this" in your loaded method is a jQuery Deferred object looking like this

   `Object,

   always: function (){ ... },

   done: function (){ ... },

   fail: function (){ ... },`

This short tutorial will give you and idea of what goes wrong.
http://dailyjs.com/2012/06/18/js101-this/

To make this work, provided you call activate like that `viewModel.activate()`, change `.then(loaded)` to `.then($.proxy(loaded, this))` in your `getNewInkoopFactuurAanleveren` function. This should make the this in your `loaded` function be the viewmodel object.

You should however decide on a better way to build reusable modules or classes in your application and creating constructor functions inside those RequireJS define methods would be a good start.

```
define([ "jquery" ], function ($) {  
    var User = function (username, password) {  
        this.username = username;  
        this.password = password;  
        this.isActive = false;
    }  

    User.prototype.activate = function () {  
        this.isActive = true;  
    };  

    return User;  
}
```

Note that RequireJS will call this method only once and that is why it is better to create a constructor function and then use it that way whenever you need a new object of that type.

```
var user = new User("user1", "pass");  
user.activate();
```

Look here for some examples of how to create simple classes.
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/12/19/using-the-javascript-prototype-property-to-structure-and-extend-code.aspx.

Comment: I will dive into this and try to figure out how to change things. We've followed John Papa's codecamper SPA example and tried to use this to build our own application in a similar fashion so changing all the code might be somewhat difficult ;) Thanks for the extensive answer though.

Comment: Changing the code with .then($.proxy(loaded, this)) doesn't work yet, I presume this is because the this variable is already out of scope when the activate method on the viewmodel is being called.

Comment: Yes you are right. `getNewInkoopFactuurAanleveren(callback);` on line 10 should be `this.getNewInkoopFactuurAanleveren(callback);`. I've missed that.